# Adding href to div shifts the image

Tags: html, css, image, href

I wanted to add a href to an image. But the problem is whenever I write the add for the href the image shifts to the right of the div. Is there anyway to fix it?

Without href

[image]

With href

[image]

```css
.search {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 200, 0.466);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <a href="images/Ricardo.png">
    <img src="images/Ikon1.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: check your code around you .a css to check for padding

Answer (score 0):

The space is probably the result of spaces in your markup. You can either remove the spaces in your markup, or set both the image and the link to be displayed as block elements.